# Filezilla not asking for SSH-key password under LXQt

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, openssh, filezilla

I can not connect to my webhoster with SSH Key in filezilla under `LXQt`. Filezilla does not ask for the SSH-key password like GNOME does, and says authentication was not possible und no connection was established.

I tried and installed `keychain`, but that did not help.

`lxqt-openssh-askpass` is installed. The OS is archlinux. How to tell filezilla or LXQt that it shall ask for the SSH-key-password ?

### edit:

I am now on gnome again, but I did save a logfile with lxqt:

```
2015-07-20 13:12:58 2395 1 Status: Verbinde mit xx.xxx.xx.xxx...
2015-07-20 13:12:58 2395 1 Antwort: fzSftp started, protocol_version=2
2015-07-20 13:12:58 2395 1 Befehl: open "root@xx.xxx.xx.xxx" 22
2015-07-20 13:12:59 2395 1 Befehl: Pass: 
2015-07-20 13:12:59 2395 1 Fehler: Authentifizierung fehlgeschlagen.
2015-07-20 13:12:59 2395 1 Fehler: Kritischer Fehler: Herstellen der Verbindung zum Server fehlgeschlagen
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Status: Verbindung zum Server getrennt
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Status: Verbinde mit xx.xxx.xx.xxx...
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Going to execute /usr/bin/fzsftp
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Antwort: fzSftp started, protocol_version=2
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse(fzSftp started, protocol_version=2)
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend()
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Befehl: open "root@xx.xxx.xx.xxx" 22
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Using SSH protocol version 2
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Doing ECDH key exchange with hash SHA-256
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Host key fingerprint is:
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 26:48:27:19:eb:cf:03:af:84:28:76:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Befehl: Pass: 
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Sent password
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: Password authentication failed
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Fehler: Authentifizierung fehlgeschlagen.
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(1094)
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(1094)
2015-07-20 13:13:38 2395 1 Fehler: Kritischer Fehler: Herstellen der Verbindung zum Server fehlgeschlagen
```

Comment: Can you show us FileZilla log? (not the message log you see in the GUI)